# How to set up Webpack for SASS

Tags: webpack, sass

I have a question about Webpack. I am going to use Webpack for SASS. I think I already have Node on my computer. My questions are:

1. Do I have to install it again or install it every time I work on a new project?
2. Should I install in a project folder or a computer?

Comment: `-g` means **g**lobal, installing for the whole computer not just the current project.

Comment: Should I install in a project folder or a computer?

Comment: So you want to use webpack ONLY for sass?

Comment: For SASS and ES6. I do not know how to set up.

Comment: This might help: https://gist.github.com/mburakerman/629783c16acf5e5f03de60528d3139af